# Why do i get NullPointerException when i try to create object by POST method?

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I`ve been coding some REST API tests, and i dont know either i wrote my test wrong or my POST method is invalid. 
Im getting this error when i perform the test:

> ERROR [2015-12-14 21:37:00,309] org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler: service exception:
>   ! java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>   ! at resources.ActorResource.postActor(ActorResource.java:31) ...etc

and i have no idea where it came from. Actor object in the tests is properly initialized, it all should have worked fine.

Here is the post method :

```
    @POST
    @UnitOfWork
    public Saying postActor(@HeaderParam("actorName") String name, @HeaderParam("actorBirthDate") String birthDate) {
        Actor actor = dao.create(new Actor(name,birthDate));
        return new Saying("Added : " + actor.toString());
    }
```

And here is the test i wrote

```
    @Test
    public void postActor() {
        when(movieDAO.create(actor)).thenReturn(actor);
        final Response response = RULE.getJerseyTest().target("/actors").request().post(Entity.text(""));

        assertThat(response.getStatusInfo().getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode());
        verify(movieDAO).create(actor);
    }
```

**EDIT**
Here`s Actor  initialization method

```
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        actor = new Actor();
        actor.setId(1L);
        actor.setBirthDate("12-03-2014");
        actor.setName("Karol Marks");
    }
```

And Actor class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Actors")
public class Actor {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String birthDate;
    private Movie movie;

    public Actor() {
    }

    public Actor(String name, String birthDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "birthDate", nullable = false)
    public String getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(String birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Movie getMovie() {
        return movie;
    }

    public void setMovie(Movie movie) {
        this.movie = movie;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Actor{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", birthDate='" + birthDate + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```

Comment: I`ve added some actor details, i filled all the fields that are required in "toString()" method

Comment: Because it is the only method used in the resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `ArgumentMatcher` like [argThat](https://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html#argThat(org.hamcrest.Matcher)), see [ArgumentMatcher](https://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html):

```
when(mock.addAll(argThat(new IsListOfTwoElements()))).thenReturn(true);
```

or you have to overwrite `equals`, see [Argument matchers](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3):

> Be reasonable with using complicated argument matching. The natural matching style using `equals()` with occasional `anyX()` matchers tend to give clean & simple tests. Sometimes it's just better to refactor the code to allow `equals()` matching or even implement `equals()` method to help out with testing.

Answer (score 2):

`exception: ! java.lang.NullPointerException: null ! at resources.ActorResource.postActor(ActorResource.java:31) ...etc` means that a `NullPointerException` was thrown by code in `ActorResource`, line 31 of the Java source file.

You are getting a `NullPointerException` because your code at run-time is trying to invoke a method on an object but the object is actually `null`.

As I can't see the line numbers for `ActorResource` then

- if `Actor actor = dao.create(new Actor(name,birthDate));` is line 31 of `ActorResource` then `dao` must be `null` and invoking `dao.create(…)` causes the `NullPointerException` (which means `dao` is not yet initialized);
- otherwise if `return new Saying("Added : " + actor.toString());` is line 31 of `ActorResource` then `actor` must be `null` and invoking `actor.toString()` causes the `NullPointerException` (which means `dao.create(…)` returned `null`).

Comment: 31 line is `return new Saying("Added : " + actor.toString());` line.
So is it problem with the test method at `when(...)` ?

Comment: Then `actor` is `null` which means `dao.create(…)` is returning `null`. I suggest adding some logging and/or debugging your application to figure out why.